# How to Disable non alphabetic characters in Textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

No, I don't mean asp validation controls, I'm looking for a way to "disable" non alphabetic characters, so when user presses any key that is not a letter(except for space), it simply does not be written in the textbox.

Comment: Use javascript to listen for the keydown event, and `return false` or `preventDefault` if the character pressed wasn't valid.

Comment: @JasonP I think your comment is good enough for an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to alphanumeric check in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434076/best-way-to-alphanumeric-check-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always used the AjaxControlToolkit's `FilteredTextBoxExtender`: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this:-

```
ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z]*$"
```

or the simple solution using javascript:-

```
if ((event.keyCode > 64 && event.keyCode < 91) || (event.keyCode > 96 && event.keyCode < 123) || event.keyCode == 8)
   return true;
else
   {
       alert("Please enter only char");
       return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but I just thought I'd share a few thoughts in case someone else stumbles upon this question looking for a quick and dirty solution.

Another simple javascript option is to just remove anything you don't want during `onKeyUp`.

Add the javascript event to your TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWhatever" runat="server" onkeyup="javascript:OnKeyUpEvent(this);" />
```

Then write a simple function with whatever RegEx you want:

```
function OnKeyUpEvent(txt) {
    txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[\W_]+/g, ""); // Only accept alpha-numeric characters
}
```

`onKeyDown` works for simple keycodes but combinations are a problem. Say for example you want to allow numbers but not symbols and a user holds SHIFT then presses 4. That triggers `onKeyDown` twice, once with keyCode 16 (SHIFT key) and once with keyCode 52 (4 key). You might then be left with a "$" in your textbox when you have code in `onKeyDown` that gives a pass to keyCode == 52.

Another consideration is copy/paste. If a user pastes a long string full of invalid characters this `onKeyUp` method will strip them all away.