# Kendo UI Inline checking not allow space and other symbols

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I use this function `blockSpecialChar` in kendo ui grid inline editing? Basically I want `ProductName` column not allow space or others symbols except `/`. I try to call the function with `editor` and `template` but it not working.

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  pageable: true,
  height: 550,
  toolbar: ["create"],
  columns: [
    { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" }, 
    { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
    { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "120px" },
    { field: "Discontinued", width: "120px", editor: customBoolEditor },
    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
  editable: "inline"
});

function blockSpecialChar(e){
  var k;
  document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
  return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 && k == 32 || k == 47 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `column.editor` to add onkeypress event for the input box.

> productNameEditor to add onkeypress event

```
{ field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name", editor: productNameEditor }, 

function productNameEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input onkeypress="return blockSpecialChar(event);" required name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container);
}
```

> blockSpecialChar method to return boolean value based on the provided input value

```
function blockSpecialChar(event){
    var k = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 && k == 32 || k == 47 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
```

[Working DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/aZoWeXOd/4)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the function to the edit event. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  pageable: true,
  height: 550,
  toolbar: ["create"],
  columns: [
    { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" }, 
    { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
    { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "120px" },
    { field: "Discontinued", width: "120px", editor: customBoolEditor },
    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
  editable: "inline"
});

var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("edit", blockSpecialChar);

function blockSpecialChar(e){
  var k;
  document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
  return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 && k == 32 || k == 47 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
```

Comment: but how do I specify those function only to validate `Product Name` only? .Demo [here in Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aZoWeXOd)

Comment: that was already unser here with different solutions. Here is one that I found and you can add some char codes that you would like to include https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681828/javascript-validation-to-allow-only-numbers-and-alphabets