# How to check if the first character is alpha in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to check if the first character in the field is an alpha char in Jquery?

Comment: Either use [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067592/regular-expression-to-match-only-alphabetic-characters) or use [charCodeAt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charcodeat.asp)  and check if the value is in the range you want.

Comment: Yes, there is. Have you done *any* research? - Possible duplicate of [Best way to alphanumeric check in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434076/best-way-to-alphanumeric-check-in-javascript)

Comment: Need to do some research - this is a basic javascript, meaning I would imagine there's 432,544 posts on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to alphanumeric check in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434076/best-way-to-alphanumeric-check-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, of course...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Alpha</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="alpha">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var module = {
      regex: /[a-zA-Z]/,
      str: '',
      init: function () {
        module.listeners();
      },
      listeners: function () {
        $('#alpha').on('input', module.alpha);
      },
      alpha: function () {
        module.str = $('#alpha').val();
        if (module.regex.test(module.str.charAt(0))) {
          console.log('OK');
        } else {
          console.log('KO');
        }
      }
    };

    $(document).ready(module.init);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```