# How to restrict user from entering special characters and allow only alphanumeric in input field in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an input field. I want to restrict user from entering special characters. Only alphanumeric values are allowed. I have implemented below code but when any special characters is pressed it is visible in input field.

*component.html*

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Name" [formControl]="myName" (ngModelChange)="value($event)">
```

*component.ts*

```
value(text: any){
text = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, '');
}
```

Comment: You can't restrict a user from inserting invalid data/characters into an input. That's why you should always validate the input and throw an error message to the user when an invalid input is recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Best way to alphanumeric check in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434076/best-way-to-alphanumeric-check-in-javascript) and check your string with it.

Using the anwser's code, you can even code a thing like this :

```
text = text.split('').filter(c => isAlphaNumeric(c)).join('');
```

Or you can use the pattern HTML attribute, it will be cleaner -> `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"`

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to assign the modified value back to the control in the event handler.

```
value(text: any) {
    text = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, '');
    this.form.get('myName').setValue(text);
}
```