# jQuery remove special characters from string and more

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "I'm a very^ we!rd* Str!ng.";
```

What I would like to do is removing all special characters from the above string and replace spaces and in case they are being typed, underscores, with a - character.

The above string would look like this after the "transformation":

```
var str = 'im-a-very-werd-strng';
```

Comment: First, you would probably use double quotes for the string, because there is a single quote inside.

Comment: You're right, but it was just an example. Sorry for that.

Comment: why is this tagged as jQuery? text processing has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Because I was trying it in jQuery.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

`replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')` will filter the string down to just alphanumeric values and `replace(/[_\s]/g, '-')` will replace underscores and spaces with hyphens:

```
str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-')
```

*Source for Regex: [RegEx for Javascript to allow only alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric)*

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vNfrk/

Comment: *Comment from [Daniel Przybylowski](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3941987/daniel-przybylowski):* It seems that the underscore is removed by the first regex. So the second one could be like: replace(/\s{1,}/g, '-') The reason for a quantifier is to replace one or more spaces with '-'. Why ? Imagine string like "something & something".

Comment: @HereToLearn_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-white-space

Comment: replace(/[_\s+]/g, '-') to replace multiple spaces with only one dash
could come in handy

Comment: Thanks, @Jasper it's working perfectly. But if in string have more than one - (dash) then how to remove second dash.

Comment: This strips out hyphens and underscores and only replaces spaces with hyphens. Here's a version that replaces underscores and spaces with hyphens and keeps existing hyphens intact: `str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s-_]/gi, '').replace(/[\s_-]/g, '-')`

Answer (score 25):

Assuming by "special" you mean non-word characters, then that is pretty easy.

```
str = str.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")
```

Comment: I want to remove the non-word characters (or replace them with 'nothing'). I want to keep the numbers and normal letters and want to replace the spaces and underscores with a horizontal stripe.

Comment: That's the most powerful answer. Simple yet powerful..!

Comment: Worth pointing out that unlike all the above answers this one actually deals with "foo & bar" like this "foo-bar" and not like this "foo--bar". Short, simple and does the job perfect!

Comment: Will it work on word characters but non utf 8 ? Like ç ş ğ ü ö

Answer (score 14):

```
str.toLowerCase().replace(/[\*\^\'\!]/g, '').split(' ').join('-')
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove numbers, underscore, white-spaces and special characters from the string sentence.

```
str.replace(/[0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi,'');
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/CV_pawan/gdrd0ozn/24/)

Answer (score 5):

this will remove all the special character

```
 str.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "");
```

this is really helpful and solve my issue. Please run the below code and ensure it works

```js
var str="hello world !#to&you%*()";
console.log(str.replace(/[_\W]+/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment on Jasper's answer, I'd like to point out a small bug in his solution:

```
str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
```

The problem is that first code removes all the hyphens and then tries to replace them :) 
You should reverse the replace calls and also add hyphen to second replace regex. Like this:

```
str.replace(/[_\s]/g, '-').replace(/[^a-z0-9-\s]/gi, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove/Replace all special chars in Jquery :

If

```
str = My name is "Ghanshyam" and from "java" background
```

and want to remove all  special chars (") then use this

```
str=str.replace(/"/g,' ')
```

result:

> My name is Ghanshyam and from java background

Where g means Global

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "I'm a very^ we!rd* Str!ng.";
$('body').html(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "").replace(/[_\s]/g, "-").toLowerCase());
```

First regex remove special characters with spaces than remove extra spaces from string and the last regex replace space with "-"

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.