# How to remove certain part of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

`(1) Website Name`

`(3) Website Name - 08-08-2013 New York City`

From the examples above, how would I be able to remove the rounded brackets and the value inside using jQuery or Javascript?

I understand I would be able to get the title from using the code below

`var current_title = $(document).attr('title');`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery remove special characters from string and more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979619/jquery-remove-special-characters-from-string-and-more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var current_title = $(document).attr('title');

current_title = current_title.replace(/^\(\d+\)\s+/,'');
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

That's what regular expressions are for. You can try this:

```
"(3) Website Name - 08-08-2013 New York City".replace(/\(\d+\)/,'')
```

Comment: What about the whitespaces after the parantheses?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 it was not mentioned by the OP

Comment: the result is not stored so will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Now with more than one digit (or any other characters inside the brackets).

Use:

```
current_title = current_title.substring(current_title.indexOf(')'));
```

This should return the rest of the string after the closing bracket.

Check out the [function documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp).

Comment: If the number in the brackets goes above single digit this will not work as expected.

Comment: Correct. A fool's mistake.

Comment: This will still leave a space in the string before the required text :)

Comment: The Q never mentioned the space. Who came up with that idea? I'm actually voting up, for I think this solution is way more efficient than RegEx!