# How to remove special characters like $, @, % from string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string and I want to remove special characters like $, @, % from it.

```
var str = 'The student have 100% of attendance in @school';
```

How to remove % and $ or other special characters from above string using jquery.
Thank you.

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979619/jquery-remove-special-characters-from-string-and-more

Seems like a duplicate question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery remove special characters from string and more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979619/jquery-remove-special-characters-from-string-and-more)

Comment: please check this solution - <https://stackoverflow.com/a/6555220/5366038> .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explore Regex.

Try this:

```js
var str = 'The student have 100% of attendance in @school';
str=  str.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
document.write(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know the characters you want to exclude, use a regular expression to `replace` them with the empty string:

```js
var str = 'The student have 100% of attendance in @school';
console.log(
  str.replace(/[$@%]/g, '')
);
```

Or, if you don't want to include any special characters at all, decide which characters you *do* want to include, and use a negative character set instead:

```js
var str = 'The student have 100% of attendance in @school';
console.log(
  str.replace(/[^a-z0-9,. ]/gi, '')
);
```

The pattern

```
[^a-z0-9,. ]
```

means: match any character other than an alphanumeric character, or a comma, or a period, or a space (and it will be replaced with `''`, the empty string, and removed).

Answer (score 1):

To remove special characters from the string we can use string replace function in **javascript**.

Eg.

```
var str = 'The student have 100% of attendance in @school';

alert(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""));
```

This will remove all special **character** except space

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex replace to remove special characters from a string:

```
str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')
```