# I want to remove the double quotes from that array object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
let pos = {
  lat: "33.5896138",
  lng: "73.3885526"
};
```

i have array like this but i want to remove the double quotes from latLng values?
can anyone help me 
Thanks

Comment: Isn't it just removing them and leaving without? If you want to remove special characters
take a look at this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979619/jquery-remove-special-characters-from-string-and-more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change all the object values to numbers you can use following expression:

```js
pos = Object.entries(pos).reduce((result, [property, value]) => (
    {...result, [property]: Number(value)}
), {});
```

Now, `pos` is:

```js
{
    lat: 33.5896138,
    lng: 73.3885526
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `parseFloat`

```
let pos = { lat: "33.5896138", lng: "73.3885526" };

pos.lat = parseFloat(pos.lat);
pos.lng = parseFloat(pos.lng)
```

You can find more information on [parseFloat() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) to transform the string numeric values to numbers:

```js
let pos = { lat: "33.5896138", lng: "73.3885526" };
let result = { lat: +pos.lat, lng: +pos.lng };
console.log(result);
```

Hopefully that helps!