# How to validate a integer and chars in a textfield?

Tags: validation, angularjs

I need to validate:

1. A textfield which is for phone and price. How can I remove the two button at the right of the textfield? Those are to higher or lower the value. I do not need them. Also if the phone begins with 0 then it get messy and red.
2. A textfield which is for the name. Allow only A-Z,a-z,space.

Edit* I dont know why my code doesnt appear here on stackoverflow. 
http://jsfiddle.net/instajsf/LbYVK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the up/down buttons you see on the entry fields are put in by your user agent (Web browser).  Under Chrome, I see nothing.

As for the second part of your question, there are many, many, many posts about how how to validate user input.

A search for "javascript alphanumeric" brought this up as my first result:
[RegEx for Javascript to allow only alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric)

If you are going to be sending this data to the server, don't forget that you **must** validate server side as well.  *Nothing* that comes from the client may be trusted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) I also use chrome! but on mac. Any idea on how to fix the phone numbers starting with 0?

Comment: Sure! Phone numbers aren't integers!  They are strings!

Comment: Oh now I understand. I just add another regEx for the numbers for that field. Thank you.

Comment: regEx works ... but you have to consider your local customs too.  For instance, int the USA our phone numbers follow this pattern `(###) ###-####` or some variation of that grouping.  To play with an example phone number `555-555-1212` looks like a phone number to the American eye, but if you write it `5555551212` we won't see a phone number there.  Considering your local customs for writing out numbers and be sure to include/allow them too.

Comment: (My personal approach -- I let the user enter anything in that field, then I strip out everything BUT the numbers -- then I reformat the number so it looks write, then put it back in.)