# how to allow only rh factor to be entered in java script

Tags: javascript, regex

i have to allow user to enter only RH factor of blood like `-ve,+ve` how to do this in java script. also can i use the same thing in java also?

Please help.

Regards

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different languages, so no, you will probably not be able to do the same thing. Also: show us what you've tried and give some context. It's quite hard to fathom what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regular expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).
Its available in java and javascript both.

Check [RegEx for Javascript to allow only alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric?rq=1) for better understanding of regex expression.

```
for +ve and -ve 
var regex = /^[-+]+[v]+[e]$/i;
```

this is working..i just checked..enjoy

Comment: He tagged the question wit the regex tag, I think he's well aware of the existence of regex

Comment: i know that..i think he dnt know how to write the expression in regex tag.

Comment: `validationexpression="[0-9a-zA-Z' ']{5,} ` for allowing only alpha numeric charactors and should be five digits there like wise how to specify for `-ve and +ve`?

Comment: what if i want to ignore case sensitive?