# How to prevent user from entering special characters in text box when length is 0?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code which prevents user from entering space when the length is 0. Now, how can I prevent user from entering all special characters(anything other than a-z A-Z 0-9) when the length is 0?

```
$('#DivisionName').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if($('#DivisionName').val().length == 0){
        if (e.which == 32){//space bar
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

This is my text box.

```
<input type="text" id="DivisionName" />
```

Comment: any character other than a-z A-Z 0-9

Comment: You could use e regexp to check alphanumeric chars:
[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric

Comment: Your approach has the benefit of being simple (you don't need to care about cursor position) but I suppose it doesn't prevent users from pasting arbitrary clipboard contents. It might be an issue or not, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The letter and digit ranges are (inclusive):

- 97 - 122 (a-z)
- 65 - 90 (A-Z)
- 48 - 57 (0-9)

This is what you compare `e.which` against.

```
if (e.which < 48 || 
    (e.which > 57 && e.which < 65) || 
    (e.which > 90 && e.which < 97) ||
    e.which > 122) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Or, using inverse logic:

```
var valid = (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122);
if (!valid) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

**Update**

Even so, you may still wish to validate the field contents as a whole using a regular expression:

```
if (/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i.test(value)) {
    // it looks okay now
}
```

Or fix the field by replacing the bad stuff:

```
var stripped = value.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/i, '');
```

Comment: Knowing you already have the comparison code, you just need simple modification. That in itself is a working example

Comment: I think sample code is a fair request. Not because the OP can't be bothered, but because it makes the answer more useful in the future

Comment: @Jack: Special characters are typed when we press "Shift" key. Can we alert the user when he presses shift key instead of checking all these conditions?

Comment: @AnushaHoney The passed event will also have a `shiftKey` property you can use to detect whether someone has pressed it.

Comment: Why not `'0'.charCodeAt(0)` etc., to make things more obvious?

Answer (score 7):

This is what you are looking for:

```
$('#DivisionName').bind('keypress', function(e) {

    if($('#DivisionName').val().length == 0){
        var k = e.which;
        var ok = k >= 65 && k <= 90 || // A-Z
            k >= 97 && k <= 122 || // a-z
            k >= 48 && k <= 57; // 0-9

        if (!ok){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

or see here: http://jsfiddle.net/D4dcg/

Comment: shift + any letter followed by any number, while still pressing shift actually breaks this easily

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regex to validate the string.
Something like `^[a-zA-z0-9].*`

Here is an article about testing a regex in javascript
 : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

And you can even bind a change event and not a keypress.

Comment: The only problem is that he has a key press, not a string. If he switched his code to read the textarea content he'd need to implement stuff with text ranges to avoid random cursor jumps.

Comment: You are absolutely right. 

In any case, this still looks like a case of a simple form validation..