# How do I allow user to enter only underscore, space, alphabets and numbers in textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following jQuery.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#name').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if($('#name').val().length == 0){
        if (e.which == 32){//space bar
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    }); 
});
```

It accepts any character except space when the length is 0. How do I allow user to enter only a-z A-z 0-9 _ and space(in between characters)?

Comment: It's worth noting that if the user was to highlight everything in the textbox, they could press space and that space would be inserted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent user from entering special characters in text box when length is 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608954/how-to-prevent-user-from-entering-special-characters-in-text-box-when-length-is)

Comment: I want to restrict user from entering special characters other than underscore(_). So this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try it in **`regex`**

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9_\s]/
```

**Update:**
Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#name').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        // Filter non-digits from input value.
        if ($('#name').val().length == 0) {
            if (e.which == 32) { //space bar
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        } else {
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_\s]/, ''))
        }
    });
});
```

[**Regexplained here**](http://tinyurl.com/kyndbnt)

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G52uA/3/)

Comment: let me create a fiddle for better understanding, I'm sure you will enjoy it

Answer (score 1):

```
function EnableAlphaNumericSpecial(event) {
        // 65 - 90 = smaller case 'a',  32 - space, 48 - 58 - numeric - (0 - 9),  39 - ',35-#, 45- -

        var keyCode = event.charCode;               

        if (keyCode == undefined) 
                keyCode = event.keyCode;

        if ((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode == 32) || (keyCode == 39) || (keyCode == 45) || (keyCode == 35) || (keyCode == 0))
                event.returnValue = true;
            else {    //check if it is a IE browser or Firefox browser.
                if (window.event)
                    event.returnValue = false;
                else
                    event.preventDefault();
            }
    }
```

Something like would help you ..Try this and let me know

Comment: @JavaBeginner the code is very similar to what you would have in jQuery. At least try to use it/convert it yourself. After all, jQuery is just javascript convenience methods.

Comment: How do I check the textbox length?

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#name').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z_\. ]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```