# I need regular expression for allow only letters,numbers and white space but not allow special characters

Tags: php

I need regular expression for allow only letters,numbers and white space but not allow special characters This is my code

```
<input type="text" name="station_name" class="form-control" data-validation="required" data-validation-regexp="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/"  data-validation-error-msg="Please enter the valid Station Name" maxlength="50" value="<?php  echo $shop_name;?>">
```

Comment: You are supposed to try something by yourself first...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Check the answer:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608954/how-to-prevent-user-from-entering-special-characters-in-text-box-when-length-is

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="station_name" class="form-control" data-validation="required" data-validation-regexp="/^[\s0-9A-Za-z]+$/"  data-validation-error-msg="Please enter the valid Station Name" maxlength="50" value="<?php  echo $shop_name;?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your regexp from:

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/
```

To:

```
/^[\s0-9A-Za-z]+$/
```

So finally code like:

```
<input type="text" name="station_name" class="form-control" data-validation="required" data-validation-regexp="/^[\s0-9A-Za-z]+$/"  data-validation-error-msg="Please enter the valid Station Name" maxlength="50" value="<?php  echo $shop_name;?>">
```