# Javascript Replace function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code :-

```
/*****html*********/
<input type="text" id="firstname">

/******jquery********/
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#firstname").keyup(function(){
      var text=$(this).val();
      $(this).val(text.replace(/[^\s((a-zA-Z))]/g,''));
   });
});
```

I don't want any whitespace in my input box.Tried above code but not working. Something wrong in my code. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#firstname').keypress(function( e ) {
    if(e.which === 32) 
        return false;
})​​​​​;​
```

You can prevent key press if white space. So that no one can type it.

Comment: This is false in case user copy pastes the text though. Ref:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608954/how-to-prevent-user-from-entering-special-characters-in-text-box-when-length-is

Comment: And what happens if the user paste the code in input ?

Comment: @AndreiTodorut you are right. then this code will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is wrong. Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/w1uqqsc3/

```
$(this).val(text.replace(/[\s((0-9))]/g,''));
```

Use this app for regex http://regexr.com/

There you can find references about regex.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

```
$("#firstname").keyup(function(){
  var text=$(this).val();
  $(this).val(text.replace(/[^(a-zA-Z)]/g,''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do replacement during keyup event, you might face cursor jump issues while trying to edit the text.

I would prefer to allow them typing whatever they want and clean-up the text during change event as below (This would work perfectly for copy-paste scenario too):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#firstname").change(function(){
      var text=$(this).val();
      $(this).val(text.replace(/\s/g,''));
   });
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pnaveen/w1uqqsc3/2/