# JavaScript to check if HTML input value contains letter and number

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to get some JavaScript code together that would take in a value from a html input box and would return true if it contained both a letter (A-Z or a-z) and a digit (0-9) in any order.

So A1, a1, 1a, 1A, aAaAaA1, 111111a etc would all return true.

aa and 11 would return false because they only contain one group and not both.

Can anyone suggest how I could make this happen in JavaScript? I'm just stuck at how JavaScript would evaluate the value... everything else is working.

Thanks!

Comment: You've almost written a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for the task to the question ; ).

Comment: Regular expressions are you friend here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Your attempt please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm quite new to regex and was really struggling with that. Still trying to get my head around it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    str = "llf2ds";
    var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/;
    alert(re.test(str))
```

Comment: Hi Sampath, thanks for the reply. Using your regex it still doesnt appear to be working. I have "else if (!pass1.value.match("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])$/")) {..." but it is entering this even with letters and numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to get this to work since yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like this:

```
function foo(inpval) {

    var letmatch = inpval.match(/[a-z]/g);
    var digmatch= inpval.match(/[0-9]/g);

    if(letmatch && digmatch) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be useful:
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-password/

Validation, that passwords must contain at least six characters, including uppercase, lowercase letters and numbers.