# Skipping the special characters from users input of a text string and adding Hyphen after every word in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Html:

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter page title name" id="text" style="width: 500px;" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button" />
```

USER INPUT :: " Is this Ram's pen ? " (Without double quote)

When user click the button, the input should be..

EXPECTED :: " Is-this-Rams-pen " (Without double quote)

Main aim is to adding Hyphen(-) in between every word and skipping the other special characters.

Is it possible in Javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code.

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {

    var str = $('#text').val();

  $('#text').val((str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').trim().replace(/[_\s]/g, '-')));
})
```

`replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')`  filters the string to just alphanumeric characters.
`replace(/[_\s]/g, '-')` replaces all underscores and spaces with hyphens.

Source of Regex: [RegEx for Javascript to allow only alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric)

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/spr0dnsr/)**

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your reply. But it's seems not working. https://jsfiddle.net/fbhs5wyo/

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 replace statements

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, "-").replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d]+/g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to select all the text (along with space) which does not have special characters and then replacing spaces with `-`

```js
$('#button').on('click', function() {

    var str = $('#text').val();

  $('#text').val((str.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/gi).join('').trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-')));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter page title name" id="text" style="width: 500px;" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button" />
```

Comment: thanks :) You are great !! If it is possible then answer my question. How can i do multiple things in javascript when user clicks a button ?

Comment: @Lipak what all are your multiple things ??  You can write your script inside the click function