# Quick way to extract alphanumeric characters from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that I can write a simple loop to check each character in a string and see if it is a alphanumeric character. If it is one, concat it to a new string. And thats it.

But, is there a more elegant shortcut to do so. I have a string (with CSS selectors to be precise) and I need to extract only alphanumeric characters from that string.

Comment: Sometimes you cannot be both short and elegant while being quick at the same time.

Comment: View this entry from 2008: "[RegEx for JavaScript to allow only alphanumeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric)".

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek but in this case you can

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Many ways to do it, basic regular expression with replace

```js
var str = "123^&*^&*^asdasdsad";
var clean = str.replace(/[^0-9A-Z]+/gi,"");
console.log(str);
console.log(clean);
```

Comment: `\d` is probably better than `0-9`

Comment: The "i" is what i missed in my attempts!

Answer (score 1):

```
"sdfasfasdf1 yx6fg4 { df6gjn0 } yx".match(/([0-9a-zA-Z ])/g).join("")
```

where `sdfasfasdf1 yx6fg4 { df6gjn0 } yx` can be replaced by string variable. For example

```
var input = "hello { font-size: 14px }";
console.log(input.match(/([0-9a-zA-Z ])/g).join(""))
```

You can also create a custom method on string for that. Include into your project on start this

```
String.prototype.alphanumeric = function () {
    return this.match(/([0-9a-zA-Z ])/g).join("");
}
```

then you can everythink in your project call just

```
var input = "hello { font-size: 14px }";
console.log(input.alphanumeric());
```

or directly

```
"sdfasfasdf1 yx6fg4 { df6gjn0 } yx".alphanumeric()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var NewString = (OldString).replace(/([^0-9a-z])/ig, "");
```

where OldString is the string you want to remove the non-alphanumeric characters from