# How to remove all special characters in <p> tags using JavaScript/jQuery on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove all special characters, meaning allow only numbers and alphabets in all `<p>` tags. How can I replace all of them on page load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')` for removing all special characters. PLease follow the below code::

```
var string = "I'm a very^ we!rd* Str!ng@.";
$('p').html(string.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, ''));
```

*Source for Regex: [RegEx for Javascript to allow only alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric)*

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vNfrk/1687/

**UPDATED::**

If you want to replace all `<p>` tag's `html` and remove special chracters then you can try the following::

**HTML**

```
<p>bhbhcbh@3r5463jnjnushgd66r67!</p>
<p>jbehvbvhf6r785595%^*</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('p').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(text.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, ''));
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to replace multiple paragraph tags at a time