# Regular expression for not including a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regular expression for a string, if that string exit then it should return false.

i am using it on select option, so if value is **Please select** then it will be false

My impression:

```
^/(?!Please select)([a-z0-9]+)$
```

Got working expression as: `/^(?!.*Please select)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/`

Comment: I think there might be few typos (exit -> exists?), so please fix them to make your problem clearer to others... also please include relevant test cases and expected output...

Comment: If you want to match it when it is not present you could use `^(?!.*Please select)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$`. Perhaps you could also use a form of contains if you are using code.

Comment: If `/^(?!.*Please select)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/` works for you why use the redundant lookahead? Use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`. Duplicate of [RegEx for Javascript to allow only alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996).

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do:

```
^(?!.*Please select).+$
```

It will select all line that does not contain `Please select` anywhere in the line.
This will work with any character on the line, nut just letter and numbers.

Comment: This is working : /^(?!.*Please select)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/

Comment: @ShivSingh No, try to add a `.` or `%` other symbol to the line with your regex.

Comment: @Jotne Not my downvote, I believe OP just wants to match an alphanumeric string, and the lookahead is just redundant in their pattern. I'd re-close with [RegEx for Javascript to allow only alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996). Please consider casting a vote since my dupe-hammer was undone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript. It will be easier and more readable to find the match and just to reverse the match result. 
Something like:

```
 let unmatched = yourLine.match(/Please select/g) == null ? true: false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to validate your input against presence of "Please select":

```js
function isValid(input) {
    let regex = /Please select/;
    return !regex.test(input);
}

console.log(isValid("Please select following")); //false
console.log(isValid("selected answer!")); //true
```