# Masking for special characters in java script

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to implement masking for a field through javascript and i have written a code and its working fine with alphanumeric characters or word but the below code is not able to mask the special character entered.

```
function addMask(value) {
        $(this).val(value.replace(/\w(?=\w{4})/g, "*"));
    }
```

its not able to mask the special characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx for Javascript to allow only alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric)

Comment: First - `\d` matches only `[0-9]`, *not alpha characters* second, it's not a dupe b/c they are talking about special characters, not just alphanum.

Comment: i have updated the question with passing word in regex. [a-zA-Z0-9] its not working will you send the correct syntax for regex as i am using /\[a-zA-Z0-9] (?=\[a-zA-Z0-9] {4})/g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to mask an arbitrary input, possibly consisting of alpha, numeric, or special characters, then why not just try:

```
function addMask(value) {
    $(this).val(value.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, "*"));
}
```

This would generate an output where everything except the last four characters are masked with `*`.

```js
var input = "123456789";
console.log(input);   
output = input.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, "*");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim it solved my problem. i have searched lot but didn't find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

`\d` is the same as `[0-9]`, you need to include whatever your "special" characters are in the set of characters to match.

You don't say what the special characters are, so I can't help with your exact problem.

If, say, your special characaters are `a`, `b`, or `c` you could do `[abc0-9]` instead of `\d`