# How to check is string has both letter and number in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string `"JHJK34GHJ456HJK"`. How to check if this string has both letter and number, doesn't have whitespace, doesn't have special characters like # - /, If has only letter or only number didn't match.

I try with regex below, result is true if string is only number or letter.

```js
const queryLetterNumber = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test("JHJK34GHJ456HJK");
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts?

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? Stack Overflow is not a place where you can just "dump" a problem and expect someone to write everything for you.

Comment: I update qustion.

Comment: [Regex for password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a). Use the first one in the accepted answer and just remove the `{8,}` part. (Or replace it with whatever you need the length to be.)

Comment: const string = "QW23RLRK45r";
const chek = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)(?!.* ).{4,16}$/.test(le);  It is false.

Comment: The regex for `Contains` is: `/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])/` for letters, you figure out for numbers.

Comment: @Ismeet That is not the first regex of the accepted answer. I was referring to `"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$"`.

Comment: const le = "QW23RLRK45";
const q = /(^.*[A-Za-z])(^.*[0-9])/.test(le);  It is false.

Comment: Please see the changed comment, it should work now.

Comment: @Ivar it works /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input= [
  'JHJK34GHJ456HJK',
  'JHJKAAGHJAAAHJK',
  '123456789012345',
  'JHJK34 space JK',
  'JHJK34$dollarJK'
];
const regex = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
input.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + regex.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
JHJK34GHJ456HJK => true
JHJKAAGHJAAAHJK => false
123456789012345 => false
JHJK34 space JK => false
JHJK34$dollarJK => false
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at beginning
- `(?=.*[0-9])` - positive lookahead expecting at least one digit
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` - positive lookahead expecting at least one alpha char
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - expect 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `$` - anchor at end

Answer (score -1):

you should use a regular expression to check for alphanumeric content in the string

`/^[a-z0-9]+$/i`

The above is a sample that checks for a-z and numbers from 0-9. however, review other options as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric)

Comment: you should use a regex for this